# How To Extract The CAPITAL WORDS or BLOCK LETTER WORDS From A String In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365, filterxml

How to extract the `capitalized full words` from a string in excel ? Refer the first Image, I have used the following formula to extract the **CAPITAL / BLOCK LETTER WORDS** From a string in a cell, it works perfectly,

• Formula used in cell **B2**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,
FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")
&"</b></a>","//b[translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=.]"))
```

[image: CAPITAL_LETTERS_IMAGE_ONE]

The above formula works perfectly as longs as there is no numerical, but it doesn't give proper output when there are some numbers, refer the Image below, may be I am missing something, using `O365`

[image: CAPITAL_LETTERS_IMAGE_TWO]

Refer the cells those green colored backgrounds, it should bring only the **CAPITAL WORDS** but it carries also the numbers. What should be the right way here. Thank You!

Courtesy : I have learnt & used **[FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697)** formula by following the post of **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, and it really helped me a lot, Thank you very much Sir for this wonderful piece.!

**[Workbook_OneDrive_Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cgzhndYuVzWtTV6oM?e=BhqHoi)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the given sample data:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')='']"))
```

This would check when all uppercase alpha-chars are translated to nothing the node would equal nothing, meaning all characters were uppercase alpha.

[image]

Comment: `WOW` Sir, it worked like a `FLASH` --> Thank you so much!!! I was trying to figure all these months, but I was bit scared to ask, however thanks again Sir!!!

Comment: This platform is meant to ask questions. As long as they follow SO-rules, I don't see why you would be scared. Great you are helped, `FILTERXML()` is a treat!

Comment: Sir, if its small letters then it should be the opposite right, Sir thank you very much, I have literally no words to explain, learnt a lot from your solutions, thank you very much!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, yes it would be the opposite indeed. GL!